# what's the best path to install my binaries on osx?

Tags: python, macos, shell

I'm writing an installer and want to install the files to a standard location. The files run a number of scripts and use a launchctl job to kick them off. The question is where should I install the files? /Library or /System or somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: It depends if you want the user to authenticate or not. Are the OS X applications or Bash / Python scripts?

Comment: off-topic. Please go through the link below-
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: the scripts are python kicked with bash. they run as root.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Choose any directory listed in `PATH`.